# Ubuntu 13.04 installed but always start only Windows 7

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, 13.04

I'm tring to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC desktop but when i restart my PC, it always starts Windows 7, without asking me which OS would i like to run. I've got 3 HDD on my PC:

> 1: 200 GB with Win7
>   2: 500 GB partitioned with 4 GB of Swap, 150 GB of /home and the others GB of root (/)
>   3: 2 TB of various data.

I think the bootloader is on `sda1`, and during the installation of Ubuntu 13.04 I can't install a bootloader on that partition (fatal error). What should i do?

Here my log of fdisk:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 203.9 GB, 203928109056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24792 cylinders, total 398297088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdf56df56

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   398296937   199148437+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't     support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x272196e3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2046     7815167     3906561    5  Extended
/dev/sdb2         7815168   300785663   146485248   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       300785664   976771071   337992704   83  Linux
/dev/sdb5            2048     7815167     3906560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use boot-repair

1 boot live cd / usb

2 open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair boot-sav
```

2b Click the ubuntu icon (top left) and search boot then run the application called Boot-repair

3 follow all instructions and enter all commands when prompted

After this reboot an you will see the grub menu listing your operating systems.

Heres some documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> when your machine boots up. Select the disk on which Linux is installed.

Comment: Yes, but then it run Ubuntu without asking me if i would like to run Windows! I would like to have a simply multiboot :/

Comment: @Stizzo If in fact, it wouldn't. You see, GRUB is in the Ubuntu drive. So when it boots from Ubuntu, it would ask what OS you want.

Comment: But there isn't Windows in the options that i could run.

Comment: A bootloader lists the Operating Systems in its disk. You might want to install Ubuntu in the same drive as Windows to avail multiboot. There is an Option in Ubuntu installer to do that.